# Read contents of a file using a relative path in a Web Application

Tags: c#, web-applications, io

How can I read the contents of a text file in my Web Application, using a relative path/URL?

The files are located in a directory at the root of my application.

I don't want to specify the full path to the file I want to access, since my test environment is not an exact mirror of my production environment.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath("/path/to/file")` and pass the result of that to `File.ReadAllText()`:

```
String template = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Templates/") + filename);
```

Comment: could you please tell me in which package `Server` class is located.

Comment: @YatendraGoel System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string path)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code snippet as well.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;
```

---

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(VirtualPathProvider.OpenFile("~/foo.txt")))
{
    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```