# Deployment .NET App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path, web-deployment, filepath

I have this error when deploying app.
Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\App_Data\xxxx.pdf'.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\App_Data\XXXX.pdf'.

the app default method is to redirect to pdf file.

this is my code

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("~/App_Data/xxx.pdf", FileMode.Create);

        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
        doc.SetMargins(40f, 40f, 40f, 20f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
        doc.Open();
```

plz any help?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path file for `FileStream` uses ASP.NET relative path with tilde prefix, try using [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to map it into correct path:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/xxx.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
```

If the code exists inside action method in a controller class, just use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/xxx.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
```

Similar issues:

[Read contents of a file using a relative path in a Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832682/read-contents-of-a-file-using-a-relative-path-in-a-web-application)

[ASP.NET C# - Save FileStream on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340910/asp-net-c-sharp-save-filestream-on-server)

Comment: its give me red underline Server. and this error. An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property.

Comment: Try using fully-qualified name: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/xxx.pdf")` or if it inside a controller: `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/xxx.pdf")`.